# OpenJDK or OracleJDK for carrot2 Search Results Clustering Engine?

Tags: carrot2

Which one would be best suited for working with carrot2 source code? I have currently set it up with OpenJDK and works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Carrot2 should work fine with both, OpenJDK is probably easier to manage in terms of its license.